# Использовать браузер с допуском только по локальным сетям

Tags: windows, сервер, windows-server-2016

Есть две виртуалки:на одной - Windows Server 2016, на другой - Windows XP. Система на Windows XP введена в домен с WS. В ACTIVE DIRECTORY созданы группы пользователей. 
Одной из них необходимо разрешить использовать только браузер, с допуском по локальным сетям.
Пробовал реализовать это через GPO - не получилось

Comment: Т.е. браузер ходит только на сайты локалки, а остальные проги (какой-нить торрент клиент) ходят в инет норм или остальные проги тоже надо резать?

Comment: По идее только браузер

Comment: Посмотри в эту сторону: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/215503/configure-windows-firewall-inbound-rule-for-program-not-installed-on-server#comment437604_215503